# Async await 3 promises seems to be running in parallel, whats happening?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have 3 promises which I have created using new Promise() constructor, after 5000 ms of delay the promise resolves.

In a function: runPromises(), I am awaiting those 3 promises without using Promise.all().

```js
const promise1 = new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(1);
  }, 5000);
});

const promise2 = new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(2);
  }, 5000);
});

const promise3 = new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(3);
  }, 5000);
});

async function runPromises() {
  const value1 = await promise1;
  console.log(value1);
  const value2 = await promise2;
  console.log(value2);
  const value3 = await promise3;
  console.log(value3);
}

runPromises();
```

My expectation is to see the program run for 15 seconds in total, rather what is happening is, it is running for 5 seconds and seems like the promises are running in parallel.

What's going on?

Comment: The callback function runs when you create the promise, not when you await it. So all the `setTimeout()` calls happen immediately, and they all resolve about the same time.

Comment: fyi this is called _concurrency_, not parallelism

Comment: Wrap the promises in a function, then you can get the desired result. Change `promise1 = new` => `promise1 = () => new` and call in runPromises `await promise1();`

Comment: Why does this question have so many downvotes? Someone care to explain what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

The callback passed to the promise constructor is executed immediately. So they are executed in parallel, right. Transform them into functions:

```js
const promise1 = () => new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(1);
  }, 5000);
});

const promise2 = () => new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(2);
  }, 5000);
});

const promise3 = () => new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(3);
  }, 5000);
});

async function runPromises() {
  const value1 = await promise1();
  console.log(value1);
  const value2 = await promise2();
  console.log(value2);
  const value3 = await promise3();
  console.log(value3);
}

runPromises();
```